# Why RecyclerView is adding the last CardView deleted?

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

So I have a RecyclerView that contains a CardView and I have a button in my Activity that at each click it adds a new card to the RecyclerView.

And in each card I have another button that when pressed, deletes the CardView being touched.

The problem is that I add new rows  to the RecyclerView and I delete some then when I add rows again the new ones added are the old ones that I deleted before.

How can I fix this?

This is my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList exercises;
    private Button btnNewExercise;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        exercises = new ArrayList<>();

        final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(exercises);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnNewExercise = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewExercise);


        btnNewExercise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                exercises.add("Test" +i);
                i++;

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(exercises.size());
            }
        });


    }
}
```

And this is my adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.tv_exercise.setText(mDataset.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView tv_exercise;
        private Button btnEliminarRow;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tv_exercise = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_text);
            btnEliminarRow = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEliminarRow);
            final View posas = view;


            btnEliminarRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

        public void removeAt(int position) {
            mDataset.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataset.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Logs when adding 3 elements:

```
07-31 19:02:57.643 21770-21770/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test0
07-31 19:02:58.070 21770-21770/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test0
07-31 19:02:58.128 21770-21770/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test1
07-31 19:02:58.505 21770-21770/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test0
07-31 19:02:58.536 21770-21770/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test1
07-31 19:02:58.569 21770-21770/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test2
```

When deleting 2 elements there were no logs

Then logs when adding 2 elements again:

```
07-31 19:04:24.426 22679-22679/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test0
07-31 19:04:24.467 22679-22679/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test3
07-31 19:04:24.727 22679-22679/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test0
07-31 19:04:24.769 22679-22679/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test3
07-31 19:04:24.787 22679-22679/com.ravelinx.prueba I/System.out: Test4
```

Here is a video showing the issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgFomjUJq8c

Comment: Question: How do you differentiate between newer ones & older ones?

Comment: @Mani I have in each cardview a EditText so for example I write something in a cardview then delete it and then I try to add a new one and the old one with the text appears.

Comment: Within the method onBindViewHolder() can you print the log of mDataset.get(i) and post logs here?

Comment: @Mani ok I added them, but they dont reveal nothing in my opinion. because the text shown comes from a textview but not the one shown in the edittext.

Comment: why is `notifyItemRangeChanged()` being used in `removeAt()`? Are items after the removed item being changed?

Comment: @AdamPiziak because the elements after the one deleted change position, they move up to replace the one deleted

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Suspicious on `setHasFixedSize(true)` causing the whole issue to the existing code base itself removing this line should work.

---

Add `addItem()` something like this to the `RecyclerViewAdapter.java`

```
public void addItem(String item, int position) {
    this.mDataset.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

And replace body of *btnNewExercise.setOnClickListener()* as below

```
{
   exercises.add("Test" +i);
   i++;
   adapter.addItem("test", adapter.getCount());
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add the item now in the adapter but now trying it the cardview is not appearing, its like the recycleview is not updating  but the dataSet is adding them because in the logs I can see the size of it increasing.

Comment: Update: I added notifyDataSetChanged before notifyItemInserted but the issue is still happening I deleted a cardview and it reappeared again when adding an item again.

Comment: Remove recycler.setHasFixedSize(true) within  initViews() of the Activity

Comment: Ok I removed it but it's still happening